# Styled component missing prop: No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, react-props

I have created a Button component with React and I would like it to have a different color depending on wether it receives a boolean prop or not in the parent component.

I have created the type "ButtonProps" and passed it to my ButtonElement created using styled-components.

Below my code:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

type ButtonProps = {
  title: string;
  onClickEvent: (e: React.MouseEvent) => void;
  secondary?: boolean;
};

const ButtonElement = styled.button<ButtonProps>`
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.45em 1em;
  border: 2px solid #c1511d;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: ${(props) => (props.secondary ? "red" : "#c1511d")};
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #c1511d;
  }
`;

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({ title, onClickEvent }) => {
  return <ButtonElement onClick={onClickEvent}>{title}</ButtonElement>;
};

export default Button;
```

Typescript shows there in an error by underlying the `ButtonElement` after the return inside the `React.FC`. The error is

> No overload matches this call

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closer look at the error message shows that:

```
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: [...]): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '[...]' is missing the following properties from type '{[...]}': title, onClickEvent
```

The issue is that `styled.button<ButtonProps>` builds a styled component which expects *all* `ButtonProps` properties as props, hence the mandatory `title` and `onClickEvent` props, but when you call it, you do not pass these props: `<ButtonElement onClick={onClickEvent}>`

You just need to build a styled component that *may* receive the `secondary` prop (which you use for styling), e.g. with TypeScript `Pick` built-in utility type:

```
styled.button<Pick<ButtonProps, "secondary">>
```

And then do no forget to pass that prop to the styled component:

```
const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({
    title,
    onClickEvent,
    secondary
}) => {
    return <ButtonElement
        onClick={onClickEvent}
        secondary={secondary} // Pass the prop for extra styling
    >{title}</ButtonElement>;
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoUSWOAZxgE8AbJAEzm1wPubYFo0uSADskwmLTKVw0ePgACjMEloB6Hi1YChEUeMnlySpHABCAVxgxdABRxhacALxwA3uTie4MYDBYAuOhgoYGEAcwovOF0AYSZgNABrAFEANzEYQIAKJEDkdBgAOgBZCHNaJDSMgEpnAD44VIhgVkivCsFhVhQoBgB+QIAjCAgWFGEKAF8Kck76M0trYWSWEAznIN5WQsHF3QAeGwTE-YsrW3taABpuJE7u3vw6uoADDw5dGD5aYAAvXLgAEYkCA2iAemFQoFgaD3mAUKxWKEwoEAAyFAAsAFYQUCQW1hlBWEgoIEAExgAAedFGLTgAGI0ICsYDAa13oTiVA+FAEcByoEAMxUtqCJjQQIAElcWTAl1qTgassuhQ6ugeDDgfQIRFY+DggXwjOZrL11Wm7xgSEpX2C41omGgIEC5jAyigaBQFQJ6ESYRw5i62nFpLgAHcABa+JCi8xQWgSuCQUJWqAzTwAMn8EYg6SgbnenjFicj0bankGvv9ZSDxdDxpZbLak3ILxmc3gZyWeWIRQAYjFTnthHYIA4Gi4su4oj4-EgroXosI4scquIF1E1V0egxyJMFQ1p14iDA48I4EPzstVhlF1FYvEkk5XA-V+lxC2opu7uqd8+txqkxwKoqhwDYXqODAEYmHKY4fPm1p2ps8ThIudSuLOLCTPsqhdroKwghkdRTDM1rUPAxKYCg5hMJ2w4UEAA)

Comment: Thanks @ghybs I am new to TypeScript and didn't know about the Pick utility type! Now it works :-)